# Having two separate internet connections in the same house

Tags: internet, connection

I run a business from home and it is extremely reliant on internet connectivity. To manage the risk I am considering having two internet connections from separate providers so if one goes down I can just switch to the second. Are their any reasons I should not do this?

Comment: In a word, no. If it's essential, it's essential.

Answer (score 4):

Many people (including myself) are in the same position as you. My own ISP is very reliable so that adding a second line does not make economic sense for me.

I have a business cell phone with a good data plan anyway. Business demands it.

So I just use my phone as a HotSpot to provide Internet in the very infrequent times regular Internet goes out.

This is a more cost effective way to assure always-on Internet.

If you are subject to long outages (a day or two), then a second line does make sense.